# Java - make eclipse show deprecated code as errors

Tags: java, vector, arraylist, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to update some code from jre 1.4 to 1.7. basically I am trying to swap out vectors and hashtables for arraylists and hashmaps. I am using the jre 1.7, however, when I try to change the compiler error settings to error for deprecated code, it doesnt error on vector's or hash tables despite them being deprecated. I am sure I have configured it to error on these before and was wondering if anyone had any idea what I might be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector` and `Hashtable` are not officially deprecated, so the compiler won't warn you.  They are not marked with the `@Deprecated` annotation.